# AspNet.Core, IdentityServer 4: Unauthorized (401) during websocket handshake with SignalR 1.0 using JWT bearer token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket, identityserver4, asp.net-core-signalr

I have two aspnet.core services. One for IdentityServer 4, and one for the API used by Angular4+ clients. The SignalR hub runs on the API. The whole solution runs on docker but that should not matter (see below).

I use implicit auth flow which works flawlessly. The NG app redirects to the login page of IdentityServer where the user logs in. After that the browser is redirected back to the NG app with the access token. The token is then used to call the API and to build up the communication with SignalR. I think I've read everything that is available (see sources below).

Since SignalR is using websockets that does not support headers, the token should be sent in the querystring. Then on the API side the token is extracted and set for the request just as it was in the header. Then the token is validated and the user is authorized.

The API works without any problem the users gets authorized and the claims can be retrieved on the API side. So there should be no problem with the IdentityServer then since SignalR does not need any special configuration. Am I right?

When I do not use the [Authorized] attribute on the SignalR hub the handshake **succeeds**. This is why I think there is nothing wrong with the docker infrastructure and reverse proxy I use (the proxy is set to enable websockets).

So, without authorization SignalR works. With authorization the NG client gets the following response during handshake:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401
Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error
Error: Failed to start the connection: Error
```

The request is

```
Request URL: https://publicapi.localhost/context/negotiate?signalr_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUz... (token is truncated for simplicity)
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 401 
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

The response I get:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:4200
content-length: 0
date: Fri, 01 Jun 2018 09:00:41 GMT
server: nginx/1.13.10
status: 401
vary: Origin
www-authenticate: Bearer
```

According to the logs, the token is validated successfully. I can include the full logs however I suspect where the problem is. So I will include that part here:

```
[09:00:41:0561 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.
[09:00:41:0564 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.
```

I get these in the log file and I am not sure what it means. I include the code part on the API where I get and extract the token along with the authentication configuration.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultForbidScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignOutScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "http://identitysrv";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.ApiName = "publicAPI";
            options.JwtBearerEvents.OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Query.TryGetValue("signalr_token", out StringValues token))
                {
                    context.Options.Authority = "http://identitysrv";
                    context.Options.Audience = "publicAPI";
                    context.Token = token;
                    context.Options.Validate();
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });
```

There are no other errors, exceptions in the system. I can debug the app and everything seems to be fine.

What does the included log lines mean? 
How can I debug what is going on during the authorization?

**EDIT:** I almost forgot to mention, that I thought the problem was with the authentication schemes so, I set every scheme to the one I think was needed. However sadly it did not help.

I am kind of clueless here, so I appreciate any suggestion. Thanks.

Sources of information:

[Pass auth token to SignalR](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/888)

[Securing SignalR with IdentityServer](https://damienbod.com/2017/10/16/securing-an-angular-signalr-client-using-jwt-tokens-with-asp-net-core-and-identityserver4/)

[Microsoft docs on SignalR authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization)

[Another GitHub question](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/130)

[Authenticate against SignalR](https://www.infozone.se/en/blog/2016/03/21/authenticate-against-signalr-2/)

[Identity.Application was not authenticated](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1525)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have to answer my own question because I had a deadline and surprisingly I managed to solve this one. So I write it down hoping it is going to help someone in the future.

First I needed to have some understanding what was happening, so I replaced the whole authorization mechanism to my own. I could do it by this code. It is not required for the solution, however if anyone needed it, this is the way to do.

```
services.Configure<AuthenticationOptions>(options =>
{
    var scheme = options.Schemes.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name == JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    scheme.HandlerType = typeof(CustomAuthenticationHandler);
});
```

With the help of [IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler](http://IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/src/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler.cs) and overriding every possible method I finally understood that the OnMessageRecieved event is executed after the token is checked. So if there weren't any token during the call for HandleAuthenticateAsync the response would be 401. This helped me to figure out where to put my custom code.

I needed to implement my own "protocol" during token retrieval. So I replaced that mechanism.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;                
}).AddIdentityServerAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "http://identitysrv";
        options.TokenRetriever = CustomTokenRetriever.FromHeaderAndQueryString;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.ApiName = "publicAPI";
    });
```

The important part is the TokenRetriever property and what comes to replace it.

```
public class CustomTokenRetriever
{
    internal const string TokenItemsKey = "idsrv4:tokenvalidation:token";
    // custom token key change it to the one you use for sending the access_token to the server
    // during websocket handshake
    internal const string SignalRTokenKey = "signalr_token";

    static Func<HttpRequest, string> AuthHeaderTokenRetriever { get; set; }
    static Func<HttpRequest, string> QueryStringTokenRetriever { get; set; }

    static CustomTokenRetriever()
    {
        AuthHeaderTokenRetriever = TokenRetrieval.FromAuthorizationHeader();
        QueryStringTokenRetriever = TokenRetrieval.FromQueryString();
    }

    public static string FromHeaderAndQueryString(HttpRequest request)
    {
        var token = AuthHeaderTokenRetriever(request);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            token = QueryStringTokenRetriever(request);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            token = request.HttpContext.Items[TokenItemsKey] as string;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token) && request.Query.TryGetValue(SignalRTokenKey, out StringValues extract))
        {
            token = extract.ToString();
        }

        return token;
    }
```

And this is my custom token retriever algorithm that tries the standard header and query string first to support the common situations such as web API calls. But if the token is still empty it tries to get it from the query string where client put it during websocket handshake.

EDIT: I use the following client side (TypeScript) code in order to provide the token for the SignalR handshake

```
import { HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder, HubConnectionState } from '@aspnet/signalr';
// ...
const url = `${apiUrl}/${hubPath}?signalr_token=${accessToken}`;
const hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(url).build();
await hubConnection.start();
```

Where apiUrl, hubPath and accessToken are the required parameters of the connection.

Comment: v. interesting. I am facing a similar problem. how did you add a custom header in the client JS (or TS)? did you make changes to the SignalR npm package? I dont see anything in the api to pass a header - thanks

Comment: @ChrisCa: we use a HttpInterceptor for the purpose (TS, Angular4+). I can share some code if you wish, however we use rxjs and redux, so the process is shared between different components. But you can find sample implementation for almost every technology stack

Comment: hi - thanks. I now realise you are passing the auth token in the querystring , right? I have that working already. I thought you had figured out a way to use an authorization header instead of the querystring, but I dont think that's what you're doing?

Comment: No, unfortunately AFAIK that is not possible in my case. But the technology allows it (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#The_WebSocket_Handshake). So if you are able to modify the header for the websocket, that should work with IdentityServer4.

Comment: yeah, it seems browsers dont allow the header to be set, although you can from other types of client. unfortunately I'm in a browser so need to use the querystring- thanks again though

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel :) I've been chasing same problem till I saw your solution!!!

Comment: @DanielLeiszen are there security issues related to passing the token through query using websockets?

Comment: @AntonToshik AFAIK the querystring is just as visible as the request header, so this is more of a protocol decision than a security decision. using HTTPS the querystring is secure enough I think

Comment: @DanielLeiszen  What does your signalr client side connection code look like?

Comment: Thank you , i saw many examples , this the only that worked for me.

Comment: Thank you Daniel :-) It is working with asp core 3.1 and IdentityServer4. Great question and answer.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old thread, but in case someone stumbles upon this like I did.  I found an alternative solution.

TLDR: JwtBearerEvents.OnMessageReceived, will catch the token before it is checked when used as illustrated below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Code removed for brevity
    services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://myauthority.io";
        options.ApiName = "MyApi";
        options.JwtBearerEvents = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                // If the request is for our hub...
                var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                    (path.StartsWithSegments("/hubs/myhubname")))
                {
                    // Read the token out of the query string
                    context.Token = accessToken;
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
}
```

This Microsoft doc gave me a hint:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1.  However, in the Microsoft example, options.Events is called, because it is not an example using IdentityServerAuthentication.  If options.JwtBearerEvents is used the same way as options.Events in the Microsoft example, IdentityServer4 is happy!

Comment: This should be the right answer.  I also needed to add the Authorize attribute to the SignalR Hub.

Comment: At the time when I answered this question there were no better ways to solve this. In the meantime and thanks to this post and the github issue it raised, MS managed to solve the actual problem behind this issue. I do not know what is the actual policy in order to make the answer up-to-date without having reputation changes. Any suggestions?

Comment: Furthermore the question states the actual version of SignalR that is the version available at the time. I think SignalR 2.0 brought a lot of solutions in the field.

Comment: I see what you are saying Daniel.  This was my first post here and I was not trying to affect your reputation.  I was simply trying to share a new solution.  Maybe I could suggest an edit to your answer with this as another possible solution so that your reputation is not affected?

Comment: @AlexGemma: I also do not know what the protocol should be for this situation. The validity of information through time was always the weak-spot of the internet. And I cannot see any feature about it in SO. I am not worried about my reputation though, I think upvoting the answer might do it. As I see from the comments, in some situations this answer does not work even with aspnet.core 3.1 but my original answer still does.

Comment: I don't see an example of this answer not working in ASP.NET Core 3.1.  In your question, your original code was actually very close to this answer.  The main difference I see is as follows:

    options.JwtBearerEvents = new JwtBearerEvents { OnMessagedReceived...
vs 
    options.JwtBearerEvents.OnMessageReceived...

I'll suggest an edit to include this option in the selected answer, but in the case that it is not accepted, this answer can still be here too, as another option.  I appreciate the cooperation and the up vote!

Comment: fyi, dont pass Bearer prefix with token

Comment: @AlexGemma which version of the signalr are you using?  I am using  AspNetCore.SignalR.Core 1.1.0 but this still didnt work for me. I had to follow way it was suggested on this post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55926126/6012566

Comment: @Amir This is ASP.NET Core 3.1.  Yes you would need to UseAuthentication() as well.

Answer (score 2):

Let me put my two cents to this. I think most of us store tokens in cookies and during WebSockets handshake they are also sent to the server, so I suggest using token retrieval from cookie.

To do this add this below last `if` statement:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token) && request.Cookies.TryGetValue(SignalRCookieTokenKey, out string cookieToken))
{
    token = cookieToken;
}
```

Actually we could delete retrieval from query string at all as according to [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/security) this is not truly secure and can be logged somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The doc you referenced says "When using WebSockets or Server-Sent Events, the browser client sends the access token in the query string. Receiving the access token via query string is generally as secure as using the standard Authorization header. You should always use HTTPS to ensure a secure end-to-end connection between the client and the server." This is what I also said in a comment. Using bearer token authentication, cookies are not in play.

Comment: @DanielLeiszen yeah, but you almost always store your bearer token in cookie, so we can use cookie to retrieve token on handshake. This is common practice.

Comment: you mean the server sends the access/refresh token that is then stored in a cookie at client side and sent back during requests automatically as part of the package? I am not aware of such behavior, but would be happy to see some examples. how is the cookie created?

Comment: @DanielLeiszen For example you have IdentityServer4 and client SPA. You authenticate on ID4 and redirected to client SPA with access_token. (I recommend using Authorization Code Flow as latest OAuth 2.0 suggestion for SPA) Then in SPA you store your token in cookie. And after that you try to connect to signalR. Cookie will be automatically send to server each time during handshake and then you catch them with retrieval class and get token. After that you will have token the same way as through query string but in a little bit prettier way.

Comment: @DanielLeiszen One thing to notice - cookie always sends to the server during HTTP request automatically, this how they works. You don't have to do something additional for that. But you probably know that already :)

Comment: The cookies are sent FROM the server first. If the server is not configured to send cookies there is nothing to send back. Using bearer tokens only does not involve cookies, so there is nothing to send back.

Comment: @DanielLeiszen initialy you receive token not from cookie which was received from server, you receive token from token endpoint response in json format and only after that you put token to cookie and will be able to send them to server.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So the cookie is created on the client side and sent to the server. Thus, unlike the querystring aproach the cookies might not be logged by hops during communication. However without HTTPS that is just as vulnerable since contains clear text value of  access token. On HTTPS the approach is safer than query string. Am I right?

Comment: @DanielLeiszen exactly :) I hope no one consider using HTTP without S in the end nowadays so this can be considered as right approach I think.