# SignalR using IdentityServer bearer won't receive any JWTBearerEvents from Hub

Tags: .net-core, jwt, signalr, identityserver4

We have an api (.net core 2.2) which use `IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` for all the controllers which works fine.

We now decide to add SignalR Hub for a conference service.
The hub is working fine only if we remove the authorize attribute `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`

We did try to handle the token in the query using the following both methods *(TokenRetriever or JwrBearerEvents)* :

```
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Authority = AuthURL;
            options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Jwt;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = HttpsSetting;
            options.ApiName = APIs.API_Commerce;
            options.TokenRetriever = new Func<HttpRequest, string>(req =>
            {
                var fromHeader = TokenRetrieval.FromAuthorizationHeader();
                var fromQuery = TokenRetrieval.FromQueryString();
                return fromHeader(req) ?? fromQuery(req);
            });
            options.JwtBearerEvents.OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                    // If the request is for our hub...
                    var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                        (path.StartsWithSegments("/hubs/")))
                    {
                        // Read the token out of the query string
                        context.Token = accessToken;
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
        });
```

For some reason theses only fire when we call controllers but **ignore** all invoked methods from the client.

Note that we have an AuthServer which provide the tokens and an API.
We are using angular 7 with aspnet/signalr module for the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem...

1. *app.UseAuthentication()* was added in Configure
2. Add default scheme to authentication and remove onmessagereceive ->

   ```
           services.AddAuthentication(options =>
       {
           options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
       })
       .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
       {
           options.Authority = AuthURL;
           options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Jwt;
           options.RequireHttpsMetadata = HttpsSetting;
           options.ApiName = APIs.API_Commerce;
           options.TokenRetriever = new Func<HttpRequest, string>(req =>
           {
               var fromHeader = TokenRetrieval.FromAuthorizationHeader();
               var fromQuery = TokenRetrieval.FromQueryString();
               return fromHeader(req) ?? fromQuery(req);
           });
       });
   ```

Just to mention with .net core 2.2 u must specified an origin (*withOrigins*) and cannot use Any..

Comment: Man, I have been banging my head about how to handle the token retrieval for SignalR for the past hour. Thanks for this simple solution!

Comment: Best solution, Thank you!

Comment: you are life saver. was banging head for whole daya